# Sonido de fondo de Formulario

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo un metodo;

```
    public void SonidoAmbiente()
    {
        sonidoEntradaCarga = new SoundPlayer("Resources\\Sonidos\\ambient.wav");
        sonidoEntradaCarga.PlayLooping();       
    }
```

que lanzo al iniciar mi aplicación, el audio se escucha perfecto, el problema es que quiero que se esté reproduciendo siempre que la App este en ejecución.

Pero al lanzar otro sonido (cualquiera, de la misma manera) este sonido de fondo se detiene.

Intenté lanzar el sonido mediante un `Task`pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Hector me podrías dar la información del namespace de la clase `SoundPlayer`  para ver si este tiene alguna función loop.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza creo que te refieres a esto `using System.Media;`

Comment: Hector Lopez puedes decirme la versión de NetFramework que estas usando y si puedes cambiar de Clase para reproducir el audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por mas que probé no pude reproducir ambos audios al mismo tiempo con la Clase `SoundPlayer` creo que al parecer usa una misma instancia para reproducir el audio cosa que  cuando haces `play()` reemplaza el audio que ya esta siendo reproducido (esta es una suposición al no encontrar documentación del flujo que sigue). Por ello te recomiendo que uses la clase `MediaPlayer`. Acontinuacion paso a explicarte como usarlo.

**Agregar las referencias para ser usado**

Para que uses dicha clase deberás agregar dos referencias a tu proyecto  las cuales son `PresentationCore` y `WindowsBase`, estas referencias las encuentras en los Assemblies.

**Codigo**

Ya teniendo las referencias solo agregas el `using System.Windows.Media;` para que puedas usar la clase. Como dato especial no necesitaras ejecutar un `Thread` para reproducir los sonidos uno sobre otro sino que inicializando el objecto  podrás reproducirlo en simultaneo.

Fuente SOen: [Play two sounds simultaneusly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly)

```
using System.Windows.Media;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MediaPlayer d = new MediaPlayer();
    d.Open(new System.Uri(@"archivo2.wav"));
    d.Play();

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MediaPlayer c = new MediaPlayer();
    c.Open(new System.Uri(@"archivo1.wav"));
    c.Play();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para reproducir ambos audios necesitarias hacer uso de dos variables `SoundPlayer` distintas

```
private SoundPlayer sonidoEntradaCarga;

public void SonidoAmbiente()
{
    sonidoEntradaCarga = new SoundPlayer("Resources\\Sonidos\\ambient.wav");
    sonidoEntradaCarga.PlayLooping();       
}

public void Sonido2()
{
    var sonido2 = new SoundPlayer("Resources\\Sonidos\\sonido2.wav");
    sonido2.Play();       
}
```

si haces un `new` de la variable existente estaria anulando esa reproduccion

[Playing sounds simultaneously](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/abc86695-20c6-4dcd-82cb-544a9111cd11/playing-sounds-simultaneously?forum=csharpgeneral)

[Playing multiple sounds simultaneously with SoundPlayer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d5e44522-43fe-491d-b59d-f7c95793a8bf/playing-multiple-sounds-simultaneously-with-soundplayer?forum=winforms)

Comment: No es problema de la instanciacion del sonido ya que la idea es que solo sea llamado una vez, en la ejecución del programa y ya no se detenga hasta su finalización, tiene su variable propia y sigue sucediendo lo mismo, probare con el primero de los enlaces que has proporcionado. Gracias